# What is command after chroot {dir.} supposed to be for

Tags: command-line, chroot

what is command after chroot {dir.} supposed to be for?

seen instruction like:

```
$ TERM=$TERM chroot /mnt bash -l
```

what is the command after chroot: `bash -l` interpreted as?

Comment: That starts a "login shell" -- See [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files)

Answer (score 1):

Man page for [chroot](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/chroot.1.html):

> SYNOPSIS
> `chroot` [*OPTION*] *NEWROOT* [*COMMAND* [*ARG*]...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
> Run *COMMAND* with root directory set to *NEWROOT*.

Answer (score 1):

See the [manual page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chroot). The `chroot` command launches a command with a new root directory. In your example, `/mnt` is the new root, and `bash -l` is the command whose root will be `/mnt`. As stated by the comment, `-l` makes the shell act like a login shell.